# which is better to use in v4l2 framework, user pointer or mmap

Tags: linux, mmap, v4l2

After going through these links,

1. https://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/uapi/v4l/userp.html
2. https://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/uapi/v4l/mmap.html

I understood that there are two ways to create a buffer in v4l2 framework

1. Userpointer buffer: buffer will be created in user space.
2. Memory buffer: Buffer will be created in kernel space.

I have bit confused, which one to use while doing v4l2 driver development. I mean, which is better approach in terms of performance and handling buffer?

I will be using DMS-SG for data transfer in my hardware.

Comment: You should revise the question to avoid the opinions like *"which is better"*. Answers that solicit opinions are generally off-topic. Instead, describe your use case and ask which you should use and why.

Comment: I would like to know whether to use 
1) usr-ptr or
2) mmap in v4l2. 

If i use, user-ptr what is advantage 
If I use, mmap what is advantage.

In both case, I want to copy video data from device to test application.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.. on your requirements.

Case: Visualization of the video stream.
In this case, you might want to write the video data directly to memory that is accessible to the video driver, saving a copy operation. You will also get the shortest camera-to-display time. In this case, a user pointer would be the go to.

Case: Recording of the video stream.
In this case, you do not care about the timely delivery, but you do care about not missing frames. In this case, you can use memory mapped acquisition with multiple buffers.

Case: Single image acquisition for processing.
In this case, both timely delivery and missing frames are both less important, so you could use either method, but buffered operation will give the fastest acquisition time, since there is always a buffer with recent image data available.

Comment: Helpful answer! What if you are in both cases "Visualization of the video stream" and "Recording of the video stream"? That is you need to display and store/save video stream/images? Possible to have one userpointer and mmap at the same time (I would say no...)?

Comment: @fghoussen In that case I'd go with the mapped buffers. While the buffers are filled, you still need to save all the buffers, but if the buffers come in faster than your display process/thread can handle, you can skip stale buffers to keep latency low.
Obviously the save process/threads needs to be able to keep up with the full frame rate, or you'd need to skip (and free!) recorded buffers there.